# Get the precise date and time value

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can we get the date / time with the following format:
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss.mmm
In fact, I have to create a trace class to trace the communication flow between iOS device and another device. I need this format to have a good time stamp.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation? What classes have you seen that could possibly do this?

Comment: I recommend to communicate with the devices with timestamps and if you need to format this date and present it to the user with NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
NSString *MyString;
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
MyString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
```